# how can I send a value from my view to my bean using primefaces?

Tags: java, primefaces

I am sending values to my view from my bean and from my view to my bean, everything is fine if I work with event such as "acitonListener" but now I want to send the user to other page (with a navigation rule, it works perfect) when I click on a button, but before of that I want to set in my bean one value, how can I do this?

I am doing something like this

```
   <p:commandButton value="Send" id="sendButton" action="#{myBean.myMethod}" 
    update=":form:growTop" >
   </p:commandButton>
```

Before of that there is only a table with `<h:outputText/>` with values from my bean, any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
action="#{myBean.myMethod(myParameter)}
```

The above method expression will send `myParameter` to the `myMethod` function in your backing bean:

```
public void myMethod(String myParameter) {
    // ...
}
```

You can also send the user to the next page by returning a valid navigation outcome from your action method:

```
public String myMethod(String myParameter) {
    // ...
    return "myPage?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

In your concrete case if there is a backing bean value which is printed out:

```
<h:outputText value=#{myBean.myParameter}/>
```

the following action

```
<p:commandButton value="Send" id="sendButton" action="#{myBean.myMethod(myParameter)} 
    update=":form:growTop" >
</p:commandButton>
```

will pass `myParameter` to your action method.

In order to get the expected behavior with primefaces datatable use at least `@ViewScoped` backing bean behind your table values.